# Can not import polars.selectors in polars 0.17.15

Tags: python-polars

I use polars 0.17.15 in window11 and I just can not import the `selectors` module.

Any idea why?

I get polars by `pip install`

I also use vscode as editor and conda env via miniconda

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 import polars.selectors as cs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polars.selectors'
```

I tried re-installing polars but this did not help.

Comment: It was only added in `0.18.1` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: upgrade your polars package

If you installed it via pip:

```
pip install -U polars
```

You'll need at least version 0.18.1 to be able to use this feature